# PDF File / URL in local filesystem

Tags: iphone, url, pdf, filesystems

Hy!

I had generate a PDF File on my iPhone App.
Now I want to send it via EMail - i use the MailViewController and have to add my attachment, but now the question...

**Whick URL should I write when I only written the filename.pdf at the PDFContext?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a pdf file that is included as a resource in your app:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

To send a pdf file that you've GENERATED in your app:

1. write to disk.
2. use the path to attach it to the email.

For a detailed discussion of temp directories, read this:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html
But in short:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.pdf"];
if ([fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"success!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"fail");
}
```

the path you use to create a PDFContext should be in either the documents directory, or the temp directory, depending on how long you want the file to persist. "filename.pdf" is not a valid path to be creating a pdf context with.